# Is there a way to fix Ionic Vue input v-model?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs2, ionic-vue

I've been working with Ionic and Vue2 for a while and I always have hard time adding `ion-input` tags to my code, because `v-model` does not work properly and I have to do all sorts of workarounds. Same is with `ion-checkbox` and `ion-text-area`. I was wondering if any of you know a way to fix this so that `v-model` works or do I have to just wait for Ionic team to fix this?

Comment: this has been fixed..., see this - https://gist.github.com/mlynch/2ff3692341276ba959fea96a620097f9 not sure what your specific issue is and the vue2 version of ionic is beta software... you really need to move to vue3

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm running into the same problem on the 3.1 migration build